# Firebase posts information incorrectly

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to figure out why my Android application is loading information incorrectly into Firebase. The application is posting the information outside of it's location. This is where the information should be:

```
DriversInformation
    -UE7cSOf5Thbum6OwEmg9seAPD463
            rates: "0"
```

But instead, "rates" loads outside like so:

```
DriversInformation
    -UE7cSOf5Thbum6OwEmg9seAPD463      
    -rates: "0"
```

In my code, I defined my reference as

```
 driverInformationRef = database.getReference(Common.user_driver_tbl);
```

`Common.user_driver_tbl` is a global variable set as

```
public static final String user_driver_tbl = "DriversInformation";
```

When I post to Firebase, I am using this code

```
 double finalAverage = averageStars/count;
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
 String valueUpdate = df.format(finalAverage);
 Map<String,Object> driverUpdateRate = new HashMap<>();

 driverUpdateRate.put("rates",valueUpdate);

 driverInformationRef.child(Common.driverId)
      .updateChildren(driverUpdateRate)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
             alertDialog.dismiss();
             Toast.makeText(RateActivity.this,"Thank you for your feedback",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             finish();
                 }
             });
```

Why is `driversInformationRef.child(Common.driverId)` not accessing/posting to the correct child?

EDIT: Okay I am genuinely confused. After many recompiling, the rating system started to work. I added this line of code:

```
Log.d("FINALPROOF", String.valueOf(Common.driverId));
```

Why does this line of code make such a difference? Does this initilize the value in some way?

Comment: what if you use setValue instead updateChildren?

Comment: @Ticherhaz I attempted that. This cleared out any of the accounts I had made and threw null pointers everywhere and essentially broke my app.

Comment: what if you change to  `Map<String,String> driverUpdateRate = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: @Ticherhaz if I do that but keep update children(), the variable type is invalid as it needs the object. If I use <String,String> to setValue, it reverts to clearing out all the information underneath DriversInformation

Comment: I would suggest to do another way instead using hash.

Comment: Most likely is that your `Common.driverId` is empty, leading to `.child(Common.driverId)` being a meaningless indirection. Since we have no way to know what `Common.driverId` actually is, it's hard to help beyond that.

Comment: @Ticherhaz The use of a hashmap is normal for `updateChildren()` and should not be causing part of the path to be ignored. So while using `setValue(true)` or something similar is a good test to pinpoint the problem, it should not be required.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok thank you. ill take a note